# Limit max character count across all child elements in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xsd-1.1

I have this code :

```
<desc> 
    <paragraphe>bala bla bla</paragraphe>
    <paragraphe>bala bla bla bla</paragraphe>
    <paragraphe>bala bla bla</paragraphe>
</desc>
```

And I want to limit `desc` elements to have a maximum length of 120 characters, including all `paragraphe` content only.

For example for individual `paragraphe` elements, I can do this for fixed max length of 40 characters:

```
<xs:element name="paragraphe">
   <xs:simpleType>
       <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
           <xs:maxLength value="40"/>
       </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

But I want to limit the length of `desc` (total `paragraphe` characters) to 120 characters.

Comment: I don't need to to fixed paragraphe length of 40(its just an example) ,I want to do this constraint for desc element but i don't know how  i can do this!because desc element its a complex element.

Comment: 120 including the characters in the tags (<paragraphe>)? or only including the content inside all paragraphes?

Comment: Yes ,including the content inside all paragraphes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can use `xs:assert` in XSD 1.1:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:element name="desc">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="paragraphe" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:assert test="string-length(string-join(paragraphe, '')) &lt; 12"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**Then this XML document will be *valid*:**

```
<desc>
    <paragraphe>asdf</paragraphe>
    <paragraphe>asdf</paragraphe>
    <paragraphe>asd</paragraphe>
</desc>
```

**And this XML document will be *invalid*:**

```
<desc>
    <paragraphe>asdf</paragraphe>
    <paragraphe>asdf</paragraphe>
    <paragraphe>asdf</paragraphe>
</desc>
```

***(Just change the `12` to `120` after testing.)***

Comment: I had posted a similar answer with only a few seconds after this answer, I have deleted my answer but I think thats a new record in stackoverflow.

Comment: I had just typed "We'll call it a tie!  (+1)" to your answer but you already deleted it.   It was correct too.

Comment: Cool, we are so fast :)